# Acessing JSON elements by key using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

**What I have:** I am completely new to working with JSON files. I am currently using `Gson` to create two `HashMaps<Key, List<Pair>>` to store values into. I have gotten to the point where I can create a JSON file.

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Pair>> in = new HashMap<Integer, List<Pair>>();
HashMap<Integer, List<Pair>> out = new HashMap<Integer, List<Pair>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 300000, i++) {
    List<Integer> inList = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    List<Integer> outList = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    in.put(i, inList);
    out.put(i, outList);
}
gsonFile = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("newFile.json");
gsonFile.toJson(in, file);
gsonFile.toJson(out, file);
file.flush();

class Pair {
    int id;
    int value;

    //Some code here
}
```

Which gives me to the following `JSON` file:

```
{
   "0": [],
   "1": [], 
   "2": [],
   "3": [], 
   ...
   "300000": []
}
{
   "0": [],
   "1": [], 
   "2": [],
   "3": [],
   ...
   "300000": [] 
}
```

**What I want:** From here, I am wondering how I can use Gson to access for example `List<Pair>` for `Key = 3` in the first HashMap to then add `Pair` objects into it, and then write back into the file. For example, something like:

```
List<Pair> list3 = gsonFile.get(0).get("3");
list3.add(new Pair(1, 1));
```

to become:

```
{
   "0": [],
   "1": [], 
   "2": [],
   "3": [{"id": 1, "value": 1}], 
   ...
   "300000": []
}
{
   "0": [],
   "1": [], 
   "2": [],
   "3": [],
   ...
   "300000": [] 
}
```

I am using this method to store values as I am expected to have anywhere between 0 to 300,000 `Pair` objects in a single `List<Pair>` and therefore, keeping `in` and `out` on memory would result in out of memory errors.

Comment: Could you create a gson instance by calling `gsonFile.create()` then using one of the `fromJson` functions?